# Creating Directories and Files through PHP and Permissions Issues

Tags: php, permissions

I have a php application that creates directories and files from user input.  Is it a problem to have php create the directories/files and then use the php chmod function to set the permissions to 755/644?

When I do that, it looks like the only way to delete those files is through php.  So if I want to delete them via FTP, it won't work because apache/php owns them.

Mainly, though I'm trying to figure out if I would need to do anything else besides chmod to 755/644 for the directories/files to make things as secure as possible.

Comment: What's the reason you need to manually delete/edit files through FTP? If you really need to do it often, create another PHP script to administer the files.

Answer (score 0):

Just chmod them to 777 via php. Then youll able to delete files from ftp. 755 still allows writing only for php..

Comment: Thanks, I'm just wondering if it is more secure to have the directories at 755 and files at 644 if a php script set the permissions, rather than having them set at 777.  Or is is the same thing because if malicious php script gets in, it could still write to/destroy the files.

Comment: Yeah, it should be secure. If you using a hosting, then files are protected via folder restrictions. Eg, you can't go outside from your "htdocs" folder, neither can others. But i'm not sure about HTTP PUT/DELETE request, but it could have nothing to with chmod..

Comment: And also, as andreas mentioned, you can use somekindof php script. Google "php file manager" and i belive you have a lot of results;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use php to create directories and files from user input you should consider disallowing execution of php (and other) scripts from location where it stored. This can be done in .htaccess if you are using apache web-server.

> AddType text/html .php .cgi .pl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .asp .jsp

Comment: Actually, these scripts are run from the location where they are created.  I guess, I'm stuck in the sense that if I allow php to create files, there will always be the risk that if somehow someone got a malicious php file on the server, they could execute or delete those files.  Or maybe I would need to have the permissions initially set at 777 and have some server cron job that would regularly check and change them if necessary to more secure values.

Comment: It is better to store all user-uploaded files under special directory (e.g. uploads) and set restrictions via .htaccess in this directory. Hope you're not allowing upload of .php files by the users.

Comment: Well, then you should have a lot of trust in your users and hope they know what they are doing and will not ever have malicious intentions.